# Oracle date format issues

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there a way around this? I have to take a date as an input and execute it in a PL-SQL procedure.

```
ref_d := '03042017';

select  count(*) into count_num 
from    EGB_RDMS_RULE
where   ref_d = to_date('03042017','DDMMYYYY'); -- This statement works 

select  count(*) into count_num2
from    EGB_RDMS_RULE
where   ref_d = to_date(ref_d,'DDMMYYYY'); -- This doesnt work
```

Can some one explain why the second statement doesn't work?

Comment: These queries are doing different things.   What do you want the code to do?  What does "This doesn't work" really mean?

Comment: I want the second code to run.. i have a variable input which is a date as a string.. i want to use it to filter values in a table..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect `ref_d` is a column in your table.

I always prefix local variables with something to indicate that they are not columns.  So, I suspect you want something like this:

```
v_ref_d := '03042017';

select  count(*) into count_num2
from    EGB_RDMS_RULE
where   ref_d = to_date(v_ref_d, 'DDMMYYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the ref_d outside the function ! This might work